# Excel Macro to run Access query; show rows affected

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro On excel. It runs a query in MS Access.

```
Sub CSAT()
Dim A As Object
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set A = CreateObject("Access.Application")
A.Visible = False
A.OpenCurrentDatabase ("D:\AUTODashboard\auto_dash.accdb")
A.DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query_CSAT"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Is their a way to show (On excel) how many rows where affected when running the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
A.DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query_CSAT"
```

Use this:

```
With A.CurrentDB.QueryDefs("Query_CSAT")
   .Execute
   MsgBox .RecordsAffected
End With
```

Comment: The Macro I first presented run well in my home computer running MS Office 2010. When running Macro in my work computer that runs MS Office 2007 I get an error in **Run-time error 2501** which is the following line **A.DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query_CSAT"**  why is that ?

Comment: Dont worry, thank you this code work, **With A.CurrentDB.QueryDefs("Query_CSAT")
   .Execute
   MsgBox .RecordsAffected
End With** How do I put a message before .RecordsAffected ?

Comment: `Msgbox "Number of records affected: " & .RecordsAffected` for example.